# Pair-wise comparisons in non-parametric ANCOVA in R/SPSS

Tags: r, nonparametric, multiple-comparisons, ancova, contrasts

I'm running a non-parametric ANCOVA in R. I'm using the non-parametric ANCOVA from the fANCOVA package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fANCOVA/fANCOVA.pdf
I'm getting the results below. Now I need to run pair-wise comparisons, similar to Dunn test in Kruskal-Wallis test and to Tukey HSD in ANOVA -- even though the results below are not significant, I want to do the pairwise comparisons, in the case other analyses shows significance. Therefore I have the following question: How do I run pairwise comparisons in a non-parametric ANCOVA in R/SPSS? I greatly appreciate your help.

I'm applying the formula from fANCOVA:

> T.aov(x, y, group, B = 200, degree = 1, criterion = c("aicc", "gcv"),
>   family = c("gaussian", "symmetric"), tstat = c("DN", "YB"),
>   user.span = NULL, ...)
>
> T.aov(subsetframe$IriSum1, subsetframe$EmDiffSum1,subsetframe$Condition2),
>   IriSum1 is the covariate, EmDiffSum1 is the dependent variable, and Condition2 is the grouping variable.
>
> Test the equality of curves based on an ANOVA-type statistic
>
> Comparing 5 nonparametric regression curves 
>   Local polynomial regression with automatic smoothing parameter selection via AICC >is used for curve fitting. 
>   Wide-bootstrap algorithm is applied to obtain the null distribution.
>
> Null hypothesis: there is no difference between the 5 curves.
>   T =  4.793     p-value =  0.209

I also tried the loess.ancova (Fit a semiparametric ANCOVA model with a local polynomial smoother) from the fANCOVA package. The result is:

> loess.ancova(x, spdata.2$EmDiffSum1,spdata.2$Condition, plot=TRUE, data.points = > TRUE)
>   $linear.fit
>                   [,1]
>   (Intercept) 4.510333
>   groupB      1.447953
>   groupC      1.373840
>   groupD      1.450809
>   groupE      1.047067
>
> $smooth.fit
>   Call:
>   loess(formula = lm.res ~ x1 + x2, span = span1, degree = degree, 
>       family = family)
>
> Number of Observations: 132 
>   Equivalent Number of Parameters: 8.28 
>   Residual Standard Error: 1.957

Thank you very much for your help. I use both R and SPSS. While these tests have been run in R, if anybody knows the method for running non-parametric ANCOVA with pairwise comparisons in SPSS, I'd be very grateful to hear that too.

Comment: *"Null hypothesis: there is no difference between the 5 curves."* If there is no difference among any of the curves, there will be no significant individual difference, especially after multiple testing correction. Non-parametric statistics are less powerful than parametric statistics if the assumptions of parametric statistics hold. Can you include a bit more about the type of data and the research question? Non-parametric statistics is not generally the first thing to resort to.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm using non-parametric tests because the assumptions for ANCOVA are not met: the data are not normally distributed (Shapiro-Wilks test) and the variances are not homogenous (Levene's test). Therefore, non-parametric tests have to be used. Yes, I know that the result I shared doesn't have statistically significant differences. However, I need to be able to do pairwise comparisons, because some other variables may have statistical significance. But if I can't run pairwise comparisons, I will not be able to identify where the differences are.

Comment: So to clarify: My question is: How to run pairwise comparisons in non-parametric ANCOVA in R/SPSS? I know how to run them after a non-parametric ANOVA (Kruskal-Wallis test) in R/SPSS: Dunn post hoc test with  bh corrections. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why did you assume normality in the first place? Can a different distribution (e.g. Poisson for independent counts, binomial for successes out of $n$ trials) be assumed in the context of a GLM? Even if normality seemed a reasonable assumption, a Shapiro-Wilks test is hardly a reason to use non-parametric methods. See for example this question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/176202. Lastly, in my previous comment I tried to explain that if there is no significance in the omnibus test of the ANOVA, there will also be no individual difference that remains significant after correction.